# Why can't be <header> tag renamed in html?

Tags: css, html, tags

In the following code all the tags defined inside  style tags except `<header>` can be renamed,

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    header {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;     
    }
    nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    height:300px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;          
    }
    section {
    width:350px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;        
    }
    footer {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;         
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <header>
    <h1>City Gallery</h1>
    </header>

    <nav>
    London<br>
    Paris<br>
    Tokyo
    </nav>

    <section>
    <h1>London</h1>
    <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
    <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
    </section>

    <footer>
    Copyright © W3Schools.com
    </footer>

    </body>
    </html>
```

If I rename, say, `<nav>` tag to `<mytag>` even then the code renders the same as before. But if I rename `<header>` tag to say `<myheader>` then it doesn't render the code same as before. Why is so? What is special in `<header>` tag?

Comment: I can think of better examples. Rename <textarea> to <nottextareaanymore> and enjoy how it breaks :)

Comment: Why would you rename the HTML Tags, when they are standardised?

Comment: @MatthiasS. I don't want nothing. I was just playing around with the code and noticed that a particular tag could not be renamed.

Answer (score 1):

You can. Just change

```css
header {
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px;     
}
```

to

```css
myheader {
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px;  
  display: block;
}
```

Notice the "display: block"

here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/urL383L7/1/

Comment: But we can't rename it without adding the extra `display: block` part. On the other hand other tags can be just renamed without adding any extra `display: block` part.